# Question about Bounding Box Regression in R-CNN

Tags: neural-networks, computer-vision

[image]

I am curious why, in that equation of Bounding Box Regression, the Feature Vector φ5 obtained from Pool 5 among the trained CNN Layers is multiplied by w. Also, I'm curious about the reason for adding the L2 Normalization afterward.